# Red black tree red children property check

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, recursion, red-black-tree

Given a RB Tree, I need to write an algorithm that checks that every node that is red, has both its children black.

i.e. returns true if every red node only has black children, false otherwise.

Here is my attempt:

```
ChildCheck(x){
    if (x.color==black){
        if(x.leftChild !=null or x.leftchild!=nil)
            bool a = ChildCheck(x.leftChild)
        else  a = true
        if (x.rightChild!=null or x.leftchild!=nil){
            bool b = Childcheck(x.leftChild)
        else b = true
        return (a && b)
    }
    else
        if (x.leftChild !=null or x.leftchild!=nil)
            if(x.leftChild.color==black)
                d = true
            else d = false
        else
            d = true
        if (x.rightChild !=null or x.rightchild!=nil)
            if(x.rightChild.color==black)
                e = true
            else e = false
        else
            e = true
        return (d && e)
    }
}
```

Will this return the right answer? If no, what's wrong with it?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't know how to make the question more clear mate sorry...

Comment: To rephrase - what are you asking us to do with your code?  We're unlikely to just give you the answer here.  Do you want us to review your code and find what's wrong with it?  If so, please demonstrate to us that you've made at least a basic effort to figure out what (if anything) is wrong with your code.

Comment: I guess verification is what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 2):

```
bool CheckRedProperty(NodePtr root)
{
    if (root == NULL) 
        return true;

    if (!CheckRedProperty(root->left))
        return false;

    if (CheckRedProperty(root->right))
        return false;

    if (root->IsRed() 
        && (root->left && root->left->IsRed() || root->right && root->right->IsRed()))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```